# Azure deployment slot creation in azure not working

Tags: azure, powershell, octopus-deploy

I am trying to create a slot in azure app environment in Octopus via powershell script
Here is my script,

```
$resourceGroupName = $OctopusParameters["ResourceGroupName"]
$name = $OctopusParameters["Name"]
New-AzureRmWebAppSlot -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $name -Slot blue
```

It works in dev environment but doesn't work in UAT. I can confirm both environments are the same.
I've checked everything and looks identical in azure and octopus

The error I am getting is as follows

```
Calamari.exe : CloseError: The client '976C13ED-5E0E-45C2-8E7A-6172CD41A523' with object id 
'976C13ED-5E0E-45C2-8E7A-6172CD41A523' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Web/sites/read' over  
scope '/subscriptions/87932404-80E8-4895-8F4A-E400E263E3DF/resourceGroups/cyberton-app-uat/providers/Microsoft.Web/sit 
es/cyberton-app-uat' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials. 
At C:\Octopus\Work\20200929095107-112805-2926\Bootstrap.ps1:49 char:1 
+ &  "C:\Octopus\OctopusServer\Tools\Calamari.Cloud\9.0.5\Calamari.exe" ... 
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (CloseError: The...ur credentials.:String) [], RemoteException 
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError  
At C:\Octopus\Work\20200929095107-112805-2926\Script.ps1:7 char:1 
+ New-AzureRmWebAppSlot -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $name -Slot blue
```

I am running out of ideas, could you please help

Thanks

Comment: The error message clearly seems to suggest missing permissions. Have you verified the existing role assignments over the said resources?

Answer (score 0):

You should assign a subscription role to the service principal '976C13ED-5E0E-45C2-8E7A-6172CD41A523'.

In Azure portal, find your Azure subscription, click on `Access Control (IAM)` and then click on `Add role assignment`. Assign a role (eg. contributor) to the service principal.

[image]

If you think that the permissions for the subscription role are too large, you can find the corresponding resource to perform the same role assignment operation.